# Which one is incorrect

Tags: grammar

**The more greatly** a person's eating and **the less** the amount of daily exercise, **the fatter** and **the more** likely to develop heart disease the person is.

Which one is incorrect? I've tried to solve this for some time now but still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: _The more greatly a person's eating_ is not idiomatic English, or even grammatical. It would be simpler to say _The more a person eats_.

Answer (score 1):

I of course agree with Kate Bunting’s comment that the specified sentence is not grammatical as well as her implication that it has poor style.

What is ungrammatical about it?

“Eating” in that sentence is a gerund, meaning a participle used as a **noun**. Nouns are modified by adjectives rather than adverbs such as “greatly.” When participles are used as adjectives or as part of a verb, then they are modified by an adverb. You could correct the grammar in at least two ways.

> The more greatly a person eats

has a comparative **adverb** modifying the **verb** “eats” and thus is grammatically correct.

> The greater a person’s eating

has a comparative **adjective** modifying the **gerund** “eating” (which acts as a noun) and thus is grammatically correct.

Although this site tends to avoid discussing style as that is a matter of taste and opinion, I believe that this sentence would be viewed as awkward by almost anyone who writes English professionally. Here is **one** way to rewrite it to make it less awkward.

> The more people eat and the less they exercise, the more likely they are to become fat and develop heart disease.